# Jmeter HTTP Request keep redirecting in circular loop after NTLM authentication

Tags: jmeter, drupal-8, ntlm-authentication

I'm relatively new to JMeter.  I am tring to get Jmeter HTTP Sampler to land on a secured webpage that developed using Drupal 8. I think it requires NTLM authentication, so I used the HTTP Authorization Manager to pass credentials as specified in the BlazeMeter guide

My Authorization Manager has the following values:

```
Base URL: https:// [test site]
Username: [my user name]
Password: [my password]
Domain: my domain
Mechanism: BASIC_DIGEST
```

## From the jmeter log, I can see that I got authenticated.

2019-08-16 14:21:08,975 DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec: Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-08-16 14:21:08,975 DEBUG o.a.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator: Authentication succeeded
2019-08-16 14:21:08,976 DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.ResponseProcessCookies: Cookie spec not specified in HTTP context

=========================

However, I didn't get redirect to the secured webpage.  Instead, it redirects me to my homepage URL, then it redirects me to another url with double encoding, then it redirect me back to my homepage url and keep redirecting in a loop.  Then the request error out after 20 re-directs.

We are not too sure why it happens.  We are not too sure if this relate to cookie and we already add HTTP Cookie Manager to the Jmeter Thread Group.

Also, if I copy the URL from jmeter that has the authentication credential where it redirect to, and paste on the IE browser, and I am able to lauch the site.  It is only issue in Jmeter.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Try adding JMeter property `CookieManager.check.cookies=false`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try configuring the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)'s "Policy" to something less restrictive, i.e. `Netscape`

   [image]
2. Try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   Check out [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) for more information
3. If nothing helps you can always extract necessary cookie(s) from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and add them to the HTTP Cookie Manager manually.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried all the above, it didn't solve my issue.  It still keep redirecting in circular loop after the ntlm authentication.  Thank you!